# Solve n equation with n variables.

Tags: linear-algebra

There are $n$ equations and $n$ variables to solve. All the $n$ equations are of the form, for example...

If $n=3$:

$-x+y+z=a$

$x-y+z=b$

$x+y-z=c$

If $n=4:$

$-x+y+z+p=a$

$x-y+z+p=b$

$x+y-z+p=c$

$x+y+z-p=d$

here $a,b,c,d$ are constants.

How to solve this type of equations and calculate value of variables?

Comment: Your system of equations is of the form $AX=b$. Try to write the matrix $A$ and see if it is invertible.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is the starting point of linear algebra. There are different ways to solve such a system, any of which you can Google: Gaussian elimination and Cramer's rule are the two most common.

A good introduction to Linear Algebra is the book by Gilbert Strang.

Answer (score 1):

**If n=3**

$
[A|B] = \begin{bmatrix}
 -1 & 1 & 1  &|a\\
1 & -1 & 1  &|b\\
1 & 1 & -1   &|c\\
\end{bmatrix}
$

Reduce it to Echelon form as

$
[A|B] = \begin{bmatrix}
 -1 & 1 & 1 &|a\\
0 & 0 & 2 &|a+b\\
0 & 2 & 0     &|a+c\\
\end{bmatrix}
$

So we get

$-x+y+z=a$

$2z=a+b$

$2y=a+c$

and find value of x,y and z  from above equations

**If n=4**

$
[A|B] = \begin{bmatrix}
 -1 & 1 & 1  & 1 &|a\\
1 & -1 & 1 & 1 &|b\\
1 & 1 & -1  & 1  &|c\\
1 & 1 & 1  & -1  &|d\\
\end{bmatrix}
$

Reduce it to Echelon form as

$
[A|B] = \begin{bmatrix}
 -1 & 1 & 1 & 1 &|a\\
0 & 0 & 2 & 2 &|a+b\\
0 & 2 & 0 & 2    &|a+c\\
0 & 2 & 2 & 0    &|a+d\\
\end{bmatrix}
$

So we get

$-x+y+z+p=a$

$2z+2p=a+b$

$2y+2p=a+c$

$2y+2z=a+d$

and find value of x,y,z and p from above equations

Similarly,do with other values of n

Answer (score 0):

These equations have a simple solution.  A first step is to add up all the equations, and get the value of $x+y+z$, or $x+y+z+p$.

Answer (score 0):

Here, your matrix contains -1 in diagonal, and 1 on other locations.

So, solution is as follows,

For n = 3,

1. Add all the equations, it will give you, `(n-2)(x + y + z) = (a + b + c)`

   ```
                      (x+y+z) = (a+b+c)/(n-2)
   ```
2. Now use value of (x+y+z), solve all variables.

> For example,
>
> ```
>               -x+y+z = a 
>
>         => (x+y+z) - 2x  = a
>         => (a+b+c)/(n-2) - 2x = a
>         => x = ( (a+b+c)/(n-2) - a )/2
> ```

Similarly you can calculate all variables for n = 4, 5, 6.......

Hope you clear with my explanations. If any doubt ask me.